# Esxi hypervisor install: uefi or bios?

Tags: vmware-esxi, bios, hypervisor, uefi, bare-metal

I recently bought Dell PowerEdge T430 server and I want to install on it ESXi 6.0. Since VMware now supports UEFI (from version 5.0) I want to ask how to install hypervisor?

- BIOS
- UEFI

After install, changing bios/uefi settings in um... Bios will render the system unbootable, so I want to pick good decision now when I have the opportunity rather than changing it later by reinstalling whole ESXi.

Does VMware ESXi currently have any advantages while being installed and used while the server is in UEFI mode instead of BIOS?

Since we're on the topic: how does Hyper-V relate to that? Will Hyper-V have any advantages while booted on UEFI device?

EDIT:

The only article I was able to find was on VMware knowledge base site regarding new features in ESXi 6.0 saying that it is possible to install ESXi on a server booted from UEFI instead of BIOS but nothing more.
[Best practices to install or upgrade to VMware ESXi 6.0 (2109712)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2109712)

I also found something on dell's site but also nothing meaningful
[VMware ESXi support for UEFI](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/virtualization/w/wiki/4866.vmware-esxi-support-for-uefi)

Comment: I want to up vote your question, but there's no mention of the references you've checked and research you've done so far on your own.  It's helpful to know what resources you've already evaluated.

Comment: @Colyn1337 thanks for pointing that out. I just filled that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule is if you don't have a reason to switch back to BIOS, stick with UEFI.